# Why are sum() working in this dplyr expression while quantile() isn't?

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to calculate the quantiles of each row of a data frame and return the result as a matrix.  Since I want to calculate and arbitrary number of quantiles (and I imagine that it is faster to calculate them all at once, rather than re-running the function), I tried using a formula I found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23840214/1362215):

```
library(dplyr)
df<- as.data.frame(matrix(rbinom(1000,10,0.5),nrow = 2))

interim_res <- df %>% 
              rowwise() %>% 
              do(out = sapply(min(df):max(df), function(i) sum(i==.)))

interim_res <- interim_res[[1]] %>% do.call(rbind,.) %>% as.data.frame(.)
```

This makes sense, but when I try to apply the same framework to the `quantile()` function, as coded here,

```
interim_res <- df %>% 
              rowwise() %>% 
              do(out = quantile(.,probs = c(0.1,0.5,0.9)))

interim_res <- interim_res[[1]] %>% do.call(rbind,.) %>% as.data.frame(.)
```

I get this error message:

> Error in sort.int(x, na.last = na.last, decreasing = decreasing, ...) :
>
> 'x' must be atomic

Why am I getting an error with `quantile` and not `sum`?  How should I fix this issue?

Comment: In your example, the quantiles are computed across the variables in the data.frame and not across the observations. This is fairly unusual. Are you sure this is what you wanted?

Comment: The columns are results of a simulation and the rows are different parameter configurations.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`.` in `do` is a data frame, which is why you get the error.  This works:

```
df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  do(data.frame(as.list(quantile(unlist(.),probs = c(0.1,0.5,0.9)))))
```

but risks being horrendously slow.  Why not just:

```
apply(df, 1, quantile, probs = c(0.1,0.5,0.9))
```

Here are some timings with larger data:

```
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(rbinom(100000,10,0.5),nrow = 1000))

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
  df %>% rowwise() %>% do(data.frame(as.list(quantile(unlist(.),probs = c(0.1,0.5,0.9))))),
  apply(df, 1, quantile, probs = c(0.1,0.5,0.9)),
  times=5
)
```

Produces:

```
            min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
dplyr 2375.2319 2376.6658 2446.4070 2419.4561 2454.6017 2606.0794     5
apply  224.7869  231.7193  246.7137  233.4757  245.0718  298.5144     5
```

If you go the `apply` route you should probably stick with a matrix from the get go.