# Calculating amount of observations for grouped variable and attach result to dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

Similar to [dplyr: put count occurrences into new variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26784361/dplyr-put-count-occurrences-into-new-variable), [Putting rowwise counts of value occurences into new variables, how to do that in R with dplyr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23838322/putting-rowwise-counts-of-value-occurences-into-new-variables-how-to-do-that-in), [Count observations of distinct values per group and add a new column of counts for each value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43072147/count-observations-of-distinct-values-per-group-and-add-a-new-column-of-counts-f) or [Create columns from factors and count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35126517/create-columns-from-factors-and-count)

I am looking for a way to summarize observations under a certain grouping variable and attach the result to my dataframe (preferably with dplyr, but any solution is appreciated).

Here is the structure of my data:

```
id    team    teamsize    apr16   may16   
123   A      13             0      1  
124   B       8            1       1  
125   A      13            1       0   
126   A      13            0       1
```

I would like R to group my data according to the teams, count the number of 1 for apr16 (so just add up the 1 for each team) and attach a new variable to my dataframe with the result. In a next step, I would like to use this result (it represents numbers of users of a certain policy) in order to calculate the share of users for each Team (that's what I need teamsize for) - but I haven gotten there yet.

I have tried several ways to just calculate the number of users, but it did not work out.

```
DF <- DF%>%
  group_by(team, apr16) %>%
  mutate(users_0416 = n()) %>%
  ungroup

DF <- DF%>%
  group_by(team, apr16) %>%
  mutate(users_0416 = sum()) %>%
  ungroup
```

I feel like this is a really easy thing to do but I am just not moving on and really looking forward to any help.

Comment: Please post expected output

Comment: Maybe `ave(data$apr16, data$team, FUN = sum)`.

Comment: If I understand you correctly? it's just slight edit -> `mutate(users_0416 = sum(apr16))` where you only want count the 1's in that column.

Comment: YES - thank you! You are my personal hero!